# Express Route.post issue

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I use Express for my back-end application. But I have the problem Why there is not any problem on signup route, but when server starts it crashes with following error.
[image]

The place it identifies as source of error is `signin` route. But, what is the difference between `signin` and `signup` here. I can't figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if your AuthenticationController.signin is defined. Try doing `console.log(AuthenticationController.signin)` and see if it is defined. I guess most probably typo issue. May be it's AuthenticationController.signIn notice capital I.

Comment: Thanks man. Finally, I solved it. Actually it was not about typo, it was related with places of curly braces in authentication_controller file.